# Wordpress Admin Posts list is not showing after 80000 posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have wordpress website with more than 80000 posts. Now posts list in admin panel is not showing (mysite.com/wp-admin/edit.php). Request returned error "maximum allowed merory". Then I changed in wp-config

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '1024M' );
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '3072M' );
```

Then it returned me error "maximume execution time". I changed it into 150 seconds.
And now request not returns any error, returns only blank page.

But in website queries with WP_Query and get_posts working very well. 
What can be problem?

Comment: Difficult to guess without more information but first thing that springs to mind is wordpress is running a ridiculous query and either running out of memory or execution time.  Do you really need all 80000 posts to load?

Comment: Are you trying to display all 80k posts on a single page? If so, the answer is simple: DON'T DO THAT.

If not, try re-indexing the DB, and check if any plugins are misbehaving. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/100000-articles-in-wordpress

Comment: @FooBar , no, I just wanna to open Posts page in wp-admin for editing, deleting posts. Problem is with wp-admin, not with custom query or smt.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named `php.ini` and paste the below code in it and upload it to WordPress root folder as well as to `wp-content`, `wp-admin` folders in order to increase the memory limit and maximum execution time. This will solve your problem.

```
memory_limit = 1024M;
max_execution_time = 150;
```

Change the values as you want.

Comment: Yes I did it. It worked when I had 40k posts, but page opened in 3-4 minutes. But after 80k post this method is not working too. I have only 2gb of RAM :) But I cannot understand, why getting 20 posts is taking such memory in wp-admin, but WP_Query is working good.

Comment: Happy to hear from u...:-)